# Mapping different column and table names for Laravel Authentication without re-writing all of the auth classes

Tags: laravel

We store our authentication information in a different table and column names than Laravel uses by default. It's still stored in MySQL. When doing research, in the documentation it says that we have to write completely different authentication handlers.

Is there really not any way to just remap the table and column names in a central place?

If not is there a better way to handle this? Should we just create a new table using the authentication information?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your table/model name for authentication purposes inside the config\auth.php file.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Now, when it comes to changing column name by default Laravel using email field which you can change by putting a function username() which will return the field to be used for authentication inside LoginController.php.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: So would it be better to do this or just write a PHP script that takes the data and puts it into a table that matches Laravel's default schema? I don't really want to support custom functions just to rename the columns.

Comment: username() function comes with Laravel in case you want to use a different column other than email for authentication purposes. It totally depends on your database structure, if you are using users table for authentication and just want to use another column for authentication you should use username() function in LoginController and that will be enough. But in case you are using different table where you are saving authentication details then make a change in config/auth.php. in either case you are doing anything extra both these ways are endorsed in Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The Model associated with the login process can be modified in:

```
config/auth.php
```

under the 'providers' section:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\Models\MyOwnUsersTable::class,
    ],
],
```

However, the login process is a bit more tricky.  the LoginController uses the AuthenticatesUsers trait, where you may override the required methods.  For example the login method

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function login(Request $request) 
    {
        //Do whatever you have to do
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

}
```

So, basically, I encourage you to study the

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers
```

and reuse as much as possible from that class, and only override the methods you need to.